# Need to get JSON from an IP not exposed to the public

Tags: php, json, ajax, cross-domain

I am trying to access JSON from this location which is not available to the public (unless you are within the company firewall),

```
http://12.34.56.789:8983/app/collection/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true
```

My application is located on this web server,

```
http://www.mywebapp.com
```

I know that running an AJAX call to a different domain is out of the question, so I was wondering what techniques I could apply to get that data?

JSONP is not an option as I do not have control to attach a callback to the data that is located on that private server.

Thoughts?

Comment: Define not exposed to the public? You mean it does not have a domain or the 80 port is completely blocked or what? Anyway if you have means to contact it, then you can always simply use JSONP.

Comment: Exposed to the public meaning, it does not have a domain name.

Comment: Then JSONP is the way to go, exactly designed for this.

Comment: I can't attach the padding callback that's required to do JSONP.

Comment: I though the domain/IP/server is under your control, any specific reason why not, if you rule out JSONP then your options are really limited.

Comment: Assuming that you can make changes to `mywebapp.com` and add in a new php page, then "shuvo"'s answer is your only real option.

Comment: My apologies for not being clearer - it's not exposed to the public meaning it does not have a domain name and it is blocked from the public, unless you are within the company's firewall.

Answer (score 1):

use  [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents).It reads out the raw data, and returns that as string.

Answer (score 0):

Write a proxy script and put it on your domain. All it has to do is to get the data an respond it to you. Your domain will be the same, Ajax will work and no-one can see, where you get the data from. - of course its slower than a direct request.

Comment: Under that recommendation, then how can I proxy into a server such as, http://12.34.56.789:8983/app/collection/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true when that server is not accessible by the public?

Are there proxy scripts out there that you could recommend?

Comment: I'm still struggling with the accessibility issue. I was under the impression that your server running http://www.mywebapp.com can access 12.34.56.789:8983 - meaning that your servers are in the same network, behind the same firewall.

Comment: Yes, mywebapp.com can access 12.34.56.789.8983. And in this case, 12.34.56.789:8983/app/collection/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true is the JSON object that I desire to have access to.

Comment: Well then you can proxy. There are plenty ready made scripts out there. Google gave me this one [simple-php-proxy-script](https://github.com/Alexxz/Simple-php-proxy-script) under MIT license. I guess on reading it you can determine if you need such a versatile solution or if you drop features for simplicity.

Comment: If you have suggestions for proxy scripts that compliment JS framework AJAX Solr, that'd be appreciated. I came across [proxy.php](https://gist.github.com/evolvingweb/298580) a while back but there isn't a good tutorial on how to integrate it successfully.

Comment: Here's what I am facing specifically (now that we've confirmed proxying can be done), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340220/how-to-use-proxyurl-parameter-via-ajax-solr

Comment: I don't know AJAX Solr, but it should not matter what proxy you use as long as it can proxy all your requests correctly. As you are not writing you requests yourself but a Framework you may want to go for something more sophisticated than the PHP script above, just as Srikanth Venugopalan is guiding you in the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

So to give an official answer to the comment, JSONP is the thing you are looking for, but it's not without it's downsides though. You can find a good, short tutorial on it here:

[JSON versus JSONP Tutorial](http://json-jsonp-tutorial.craic.com/index.html) (sorry don't care to re-write it).