# How to use proxyUrl parameter via AJAX Solr

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, solr, proxy

### Problem:

I have a Solr 4.5.0 intance that lives on a private server not directy accessible to the public,

```
12.34.56.789:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true
```

I am leveraging JavaScript framework AJAX Solr to present the search results once the JSON is retrieved from that Solr instance. The UI is presented here,

```
www.mywebapp.com/searchresults.html
```

Please note:

```
www.mywebapp.com
can access...
12.34.56.789
```

I've explored the suggestion for proxying and it seems as though AJAX Solr comes with a parameter that would enable me to do that. Instead of hardcoding the library to call Solr directly (which won't work because of Cross Origin restrictions), the JS library suggests an alternative in **proxyUrl**.

```
//Per AbstractManager.js
solrUrl: 'http://12.34.56.789:8983/solr/'
proxyUrl: null
```

Are there any resources, tutorials, step-by-step guides that could outline how to successfully use that parameter?

### Currently using:

Apache Solr 4.5.0

AJAX Solr (mainly leveraging the PagerWidget and ResultsWidget - no Facets)

Answer (score 0):

Your setup looks like this

```
<Browser> -> <www.mywebapp.com> -> [Firewall] -> 12.34.56.789 (Solr)
```

This would mean that your browser **cannot** access your solr instance, so AjaxSolr will not work.

Instead of using proxyUrl, you can try proxying your requests via www.mywebapp.com.

I.e setup a reverse proxy to route

```
http://www.mywebapp.com/solr -> http://12.34.56.789/solr
```

Thus your javascript can access Solr via `mywebapp.com`.

Then change your AjaxSolr setting to

```
solrUrl: 'http://www.mywebapp.com/solr'
```

Bottom line is you need an endpoint that is accessible from the browser.

Edit 1:

You may not need a reverse proxy if you can handle rules at your DNS/ Load balance.

I have used Cloudflare (https://cloudflare.com) to handle such rules.

In case that is not an option, you can use a reverse proxy. There are quite a few options for this, I prefer nginx. [Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy.html) is an article that explains setting up nginx as reverse proxy.

Comment: What would you recommend to perform the reverse proxy suggestion?

Comment: My sysadmin advised that although firewalls are established, mywebapp.com has to ability to speak to 12.34.56.789:8983. Is it possible to proxyUrl based off of that information?

Comment: @markreyes, please see edit for details on reverse proxy. The problem isn't mywebapp being able to talk to solr. Ajax solr works from browser, which means that your solr endpoint should be visible from the browser, for ajaxsolr to make requests. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, but I had to explore the possibility in cooperation with this JS library granted that it offered a parameter that was clearly defined as 'proxyUrl'. There were solutions such as this, https://gist.github.com/jpmckinney/2123215 so I had to take a deeper dive. But per your answer, If I run an nginx reverse proxy, then I would be able to leverage AJAX Solr correctly since the endpoint is visible to the browser, correct? That being said, does that reverse proxy expose any security risks by making that endpoint visible?

Comment: The gist does something similar, routing Solr traffic via your application. Difference is that it is a PHP proxy, a reverse proxy saves you some webserver overhead. Yes, proxying as such will expose your endpoint, so you need to secure it. One way would be to add authentication at nginx level.